# Multidimensional Array Not Echoing As Expected

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am setting this array manually:

```
$schools = array(
    'Indiana University'=>array(
        'initials'=>'IU',
        'color'=>'red',
        'directory'=>'indiana'
    )
);
```

But it won't echo "IU" when I use:

```
echo $schools[0][0];
```

It does show correctly when I do:

```
print_r($schools);
```

I'm sure I'm messing up something dumb, but I have no idea what and I've been staring at it for hours.  This array is actually part of a larger array with multiple universities, but when I trim it down to just this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP arrays support two types of keys - numerical and strings.

If you just push a value onto an array, it will use numerical keys by default. E.g.

```
$schools[] = 'Indiana University';
echo $schools[0]; // Indiana University
```

However, when you use string keys, you access the array values using the string key. E.g.

```
$schools = array(
    'Indiana University' => array(
        'initials' => 'IU',
        'color' => 'red',
        'directory' => 'indiana'
    )
);
echo $schools['Indiana University']['initials']; // UI
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for explaining this part to me, I had missed that part in the docs and examples!  I had no idea!  It worked immediately when I used the string keys.  I will mark this correct in 9 mins when stack overflow allows me to.